# Jekyll filter for regex substitution in content?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

Is there a Jekyll filter that will replace text using a regular expression (regex) filter?

I believe the "built-in" filter `replace` does simple string substitution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the event there isn't a (better) solution, I'll throw in the very obviously simple plugin that will do the trick - drop this into your `_plugins/` folder as the file `regex_filter.rb` - it takes the regex as a string, as the first arg, and the replacement as the second arg (for example, `{{ page.url | replace_regex: '/$', '' }}`:

```
module Jekyll
  module RegexFilter
    def replace_regex(input, reg_str, repl_str)
      re = Regexp.new reg_str

      # This will be returned
      input.gsub re, repl_str
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::RegexFilter)
```

Comment: If you're using this for replacing HTML, make sure to change `re = Regexp.new reg_str` to `re = Regexp.new reg_str, 4` so that it matches multiple lines.

Comment: @CooperMaruyama don't ever use magic constants if there's a named constant for the same: [`Regexp::MULTILINE`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#constants-list) == [`4`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#options-method)

Comment: Along the same lines, there is also the solution suggested in this GH issue: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/202#issuecomment-19112872 (although the solution given here is more complete).

Comment: This will not work in GitHub Pages, unfortunately, as they don't run user plugins for security reasons.

Comment: @CooperMaruyama YOu eman if the section to be replaced could span over multiline than you need the `Regexp::MULTILINE` ?